# Parsing a JSON Lines file

Tags: python, json, csv

i need to find a way to parse data from a json file into csv or xlsx.
However **every** JSON validator I've used online gives me an error saying invalid JSON file.

Example of the JSON file follows:

```
{"id": "someID1.docx",
 "language": {"detected": "cs"},
 "title": "Name - Title - FileName",
 "text": "Long string of text",
 "entities": [
 {"standardForm": "Svářečský průkaz", "type": "car"},
 {"standardForm": "email1@gmail.com", "type": "email"},
 {"standardForm": "english", "type": "languages"},
 {"standardForm": "Práce na PC", "type": "abilities"},
 {"standardForm": "MS Office", "type": "abilities"},
 {"standardForm": "Automechanik", "type": "education"},
 {"standardForm": "Střední průmyslová škola", "type": "education"},
 {"standardForm": "Angličtina-Němčina", "type": "languages"},
 {"standardForm": "mechanic", "type": "position"},
 {"standardForm": "Praha", "type": "region"},
 {"standardForm": "B2 - středně pokročilý", "type": "en_level"},
 {"standardForm": "Skupina B", "type": "drivinglicense"}
 ]}
{"id": "someID2.pdf",
 "language": {"detected": "cs"},
 "title": "Name - Title - FileName2",
 "text": "Long string of text2",
 "entities": [
 {"standardForm": "german", "type": "languages"},
 {"standardForm": "high school", "type": "education"},
 {"standardForm": "Angličtina-Němčina", "type": "languages"},
 {"standardForm": "driver", "type": "position"},
 {"standardForm": "english", "type": "languages"},
 {"standardForm": "university", "type": "education"},
 {"standardForm": "email2@seznam.cz", "type": "email"},
 {"standardForm": "Středočeský", "type": "region"},
 {"standardForm": "Střední", "type": "edulevel"},
 {"standardForm": "manager", "type": "lastposition"},
 {"standardForm": "? – nerozpoznáno", "type": "de_level"},
 {"standardForm": "? – nerozpoznáno", "type": "en_level"},
 {"standardForm": "Skupina C", "type": "drivinglicense"}
 ]}
 ...
```

I am able to load this JSON in Python with:

```
import pandas as pd
jsonfile = [json.loads(line) for line in open('jsonfile.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')]
```

But I am unable to convert it into csv by any means. I need to be able to store all entities related to all ids, preferably in csv. Is there any way? Do I need the JSON to be different?

Thanks

EDIT:
I would need the csv output for the example above to be as follows:

```
ID;title;languages;education
someID1.docx;Name-Title-FileName;english,Angličtina-Němčina;Automechanik;Střední Prům. škola
seomeID2.pdf;Name-Title-FileName2; german,Angličtina-Němčina,english;high school, university
```

Comment: It's in [JSON Lines](http://jsonlines.org/) format. Although it cannot be directly parsed by the json module, it's not corrupted data. `jsonfile = [json.loads(line) for line in open('jsonfile.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')]` is basically how it's supposed to be parsed, so you've already got over the hurdle in your question. The issue is just writing to a CSV now, but that has nothing to do with the original `.json` file

Comment: To elaborate: you will need to post the expected CSV output and the issues you face in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: it's not corrupted

Comment: I have edited my question with more into on the output. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you already imported pandas you can employ its `pandas.DataFrame`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(jsonfile)
df['languages'] = df.apply(lambda x: [item['standardForm'] 
                                      for item in x.entities 
                                      if item['type'] == 'languages'], 
                           axis=1)
df['education'] = df.apply(lambda x: [item['standardForm'] 
                                      for item in x.entities 
                                      if item['type'] == 'education'],
                           axis=1)


df.to_csv(<filename>, columns=['id', 'title', 'languages', 'education'])
```

Comment: Thank you for response. This is doable, however this results in a clusterfuck of data in 'entities' column which are then stored in [{'standardForm' : 'blabla', 'type' : 'dovednosti'},{...}...]
These I can not use to store in a database :(

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

with miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases/tag/5.4.0), simply with

> mlr --j2c unsparsify then cut -x -r -f "entit" input.json >output.csv

you have this CSV

```
id,language:detected,title,text
someID1.docx,cs,Name - Title - FileName,Long string of text
someID2.pdf,cs,Name - Title - FileName2,Long string of text2
```

Some notes about options:

- `--j2c` to convert from json to csv
- `unsparsify` prints records with the union of field names over all input records
- `cut -x -r -f` remove from JSON the `entities` object

Comment: I genuinely don't understand any of this so I think you need to elaborate

Comment: @roganjosh I have added some notes in the post